npx create-react-app Could not resolve dependency peer react@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@13.4.0
When use npx create-react-app React app, it keeps complain "Could not resolve dependency", although npm list react shows react@19.0.0 and npm list @testing-library/react shows @testing-library/react@16.1.0
PS D:\React> npx create-react-app austock-metamask-sdk2 --template typescript

Installing template dependencies using npm...
npm error code ERESOLVE
npm error ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm error
npm error While resolving: austock-metamask-sdk2@0.1.0
npm error Found: react@19.0.0
npm error node_modules/react
npm error   react@"^19.0.0" from the root project
npm error
npm error Could not resolve dependency:
npm error peer react@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@13.4.0
npm error node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm error   @testing-library/react@"^13.0.0" from the root project
npm error
npm error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm error this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm error
npm error
npm error For a full report see:
npm error C:\Users\weizh\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-12-16T12_59_03_556Z-eresolve-report.txt
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\weizh\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-12-16T12_59_03_556Z-debug-0.log

PS D:\React> npm list @testing-library/react
React@ D:\React
`-- @testing-library/react@16.1.0

PS D:\React> npm list react
React@ D:\React
`-- @testing-library/react@16.1.0
  +-- react-dom@19.0.0
  | `-- react@19.0.0 deduped
  `-- react@19.0.0

PS D:\React> npx -v
10.9.2

PS D:\React> npm -v
10.9.2

PS D:\React> node -v
v22.12.0


hi, did you try " npx create-react-app austock-metamask-sdk2 --template typescript --force " command?

npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
